# Online Rules for Primordial Soup: Freshly Spiced

Tags: primordial-soup, primordial-soup-fs

Are detailed rules for the extension [Primordial Soup: Freshly Spiced](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2005/primordial-soup-freshly-spiced) available online?

All I found online is a [low quality picture of the cards](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/760250/primordial-soup-freshly-spiced?size=original) and an [analysis of the new genes](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/303203/analysis-of-the-new-genes).
And the linked [Official English Rulebook](http://boardgamegeek.com/weblink/163852/official-english-rulebook-z-man-games) doesen't show the details of the genes.

[image]

Comment: I've tried to rephrase it to read as a question, and hopefully kept the original request intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this player aid file available here:

http://www.boardgamegeek.com/filepage/1493/ursuppe-fisch-abgeschmeckt-rulespdf

The final 2 pages have a list of all of the genes in the expansion plus their description/explanation.  This should give you all of the information that you need.